# How to convert List to Row with multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Create a DataFrame from csv file, process each row, want to create a new row with the same number of columns.

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("data.csv")
def process(line: Row) : Seq[String] = {
  val list = new ArrayList[String]
  for (i <- 0 to line.size-1) {
    list.add(line.getString(i).toUpperCase)
  }
  list.asScala.toSeq
}
val df2 = df.map(process(_))
df2.show
```

Expecting/hope-to-get:

```
+---+---+---+                                                                   
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
| X1| X2| X3|
| Y1| Y2| Y3|
+---+---+---+
```

Getting:

```
+------------+                                                                     
|       value|
+------------+
|[X1, X2, X3]|
|[Y1, Y2, Y3]|
+------------+
```

Input file data.csv:

```
x1,x2,x3
y1,y2,y3
```

Note that the code should work in this input file as well:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4
y1,y2,y3,y4
```

And for this input file, I'd like to see result

```
+---+---+---+---+                                                               
| _1| _2| _3| _4|
+---+---+---+---+
| X1| X2| X3| X4|
| Y1| Y2| Y3| Y4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Please note that I used tpUpperCase() in process() just to make the simple example to work. The real logic in process() can be a lot more complex.

Comment: could you please put the content of the file `cat data.csv`

Comment: @usml . Return Type ( From process method)should be a Row not Seq(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second Update to Change rdd to Row**

**@USML** , basically changed **Seq[String]** to **Row** so that rdd can be **paralellized**. it's a distributed parallel collection that needs to be **serialized**

```
val df2 = csvDf.rdd.map(process(_)).map(a => Row.fromSeq(a)) 
//df2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
// And we use dynamic Schema (e.g. same number of columns as csv
spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema = dynamicSchema).show(false)
+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
|X1 |X2 |X3 |
|Y1 |Y2 |Y3 |
+---+---+---+
```

**Update on Changed Requirement**
As long as you are **reading** the CSV , end output will have **same** numbers of **columns** as your csv as we are using **df.schema** to create **dataframe** after calling **process** method. Try this:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("data.csv")
val dynamicSchema = df.schema // This makes sure to prserve  same number of columns
def process(line: Row) : Seq[String] = {
  val list = new ArrayList[String]
  for (i <- 0 to line.size-1) {
    list.add(line.getString(i).toUpperCase)
  }
  list.asScala.toSeq
}
val df2 = df.rdd.map(process(_)).map(a => Row.fromSeq(a)) // df2 is actually an RDD // updated conversion to Row

val finalDf = spark.createDataFrame(df2, schema = dynamicSchema) // We use same schema

finalDf.show(false)
```

**File Contents** =>

```
cat data.csv
a1,b1,c1,d1
a2,b2,c2,d2
```

**Code** =>

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val csvDf = spark.read.csv("data.csv")
csvDf.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|
+---+---+---+---+
|a1 |b1 |c1 |d1 |
|a2 |b2 |c2 |d2 |
+---+---+---+---+

def process(cols: Row): Row  = { Row("a", "b", "c","d") } // Check the Data Type

val df2 = csvDf.rdd.map(process(_)) // df2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]

val finalDf = spark.createDataFrame(df2,schema = csvDf.schema)

finalDf.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|
+---+---+---+---+
|a  |b  |c  |d  |
|a  |b  |c  |d  |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Points to note *Row* data type is needed to **Map** a Row

Better practice to have a **type safe case class**
Rest should be easy

Comment: Thanks SanBan. Sorry my question was not clear. I have edited it with working code (but not generating results I want). Basically the problem is the number of columns in the final DataFrame is not known at compile time.

Comment: I get error when trying it with spark-shell in aws/emr (emr-5.27.0, Spark 2.4.4). I'll add it to the end of original post. Thanks.